# Does it make sense to make the entire item in a list clickable, with a button inside it?

Tags: buttons, lists, hover

It's about a desktop app in which users can open a modal containing a list of items. Some of these items may have one type of action associated with them.

Does it make sense to make the entire item clickable while also retaining the button?

[image]

Comment: Is this web content? Because, besides that it's fine to do from UX perspective, the technical implementation can be a bit hard from accessibility point of view. Be aware that the button should be technically outside the clickable area and has to be styled so that it is visually inside.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, definitely. It's totally fine to keep the whole row clickable while also keeping the button in some cases. Why?

1. Keeping the whole item clickable it makes it easier for users to click it. It's bigger, mistake/off mouse friendly, you can reach the goal faster
2. Otherwise you would need to make item name clickable, which requires the user to be slower, more precised.
3. Especially if you don't have the button in all the rows, it's just more friendly to keep the whole item clickable, similar reason to point 1.

Just make sure the button is easy to click, has hover state so you can distinguish when you hover over button and when over the row only:)